# How to ignore the ssl certificate error in cordova android 5.1.1

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk

When I launch the webview with https with local certificate then I am not able to launch the url because of security issues.
Is there any way to bypass that check. I am using crosswalk plugin inside cordova and android version is 5.1.1

Comment: If it is for test, simply having an application in debug mode should be ok.

Comment: No its not ok..

Comment: @Nishant did you found a solution?